# Best way to only search for Excel files

Tags: php

So I've made this `Upload file` function on my php page. What this function does is uploading the file into a folder with the same name as the file. The user can choose a lot of different projects, from a dropdown. When the user picks a project with a existing file, another function will scan all the information from the Excel file.
My question here is:

**How can I search for only existing Excel files, and not every single file in the directory?**

**Code:**

```php
/**
 * Checks if there is an existing uploaded RVTM file. File was uploaded through 'upload.php'.
 *
 * @access      public
 * @param       string                      $fileName       Name of the spreadsheet file
 * @param       array                       $OverviewResult Array of information about verdicts, TestSuiteCollectionIds, and TestJobIds
 * @author      Mads Sander Hoegstrup
 */
function Create_Table_RVTM($fileName, $OverviewResult){
    #Scan directory for any files, and return them (should only be a single file), when  the file is deleted the directory is whiped clean: Delete_RVTM_file(...)
    $dir    = "./DashboardFiles/files/".$fileName;
    $FindFiles = scandir($dir);
    $files = array_values(array_diff($FindFiles, array('.', '..')));
    if ($files) {
        $path = "./DashboardFiles/files/".$fileName."/".$files[0];
        echo "<br>The file $fileName exists";
        RVTM_Excel($fileName, $OverviewResult, $path);
    }else {
        echo "<br>The file $fileName does not exists";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP builds in [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with a wildcard something like

```
<?php
foreach (glob("/path/to/folder/*.xl*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: keep in mind that `glob` will get all the filenames into memory, so it will run slow if the folder is huge

Comment: Thanks this was just what I needed, the folders will only contain a single file

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by looking at the file extension, for example `.xls`.

Here is the full list
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247

```
.xlsx
.xlsm
.xlsb
.xltx
.xltm
.xls
.xlt
.xls
.xlam
.xla
.xlw
.xlr
```

and here you can see how to get a file extension

```
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

and read the directory using spl
https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/directory-list-spl/

```php
  use \DirectoryIterator;

  function getFileList($dir)
  {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = [];

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open directory for reading
    $d = new DirectoryIterator($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    foreach($d as $fileinfo) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($fileinfo->isDot()) continue;
      $retval[] = [
        'name' => "{$dir}{$fileinfo}",
        'type' => ($fileinfo->getType() == "dir") ? "dir" : mime_content_type($fileinfo->getRealPath()),
        'size' => $fileinfo->getSize(),
        'lastmod' => $fileinfo->getMTime()
      ];
    }

    return $retval;
  }
```